# How to draw walls in plotly

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I have made some code to draw a room with matplotlib. I am using something like this pseudocode:

```
for i in range(totalwalls-1):
    rec=[(xa, ya, za),
         (xb, yb, zb),
         (xc, yc, zc),
         (xd, yd, zd),
         ]
    face = mp3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection([rec], linewidth=1)
    alpha = 0.12
    face.set_facecolor((0.3,0.3,0.8) + (alpha,))
    face.set_edgecolor((0.4,0.4,0.4,0.9))
    ax.add_collection3d(face)
```

I am able to draw any kind of room. For example, a room with 5 walls, where the vertex coordinates are: x=[0, 3, 4, 3, 0] y=[0, 0, 2, 4, 4] height: from 0 to 2.2. The result is like this:

[Pentagonal room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fazD9.png)

I am now interested in doing something similar with plotly and compare the results. I was going to use surface for the walls and scatter3d for the polygons, since I want to see the lines of the polygons.
I wrote this simple example:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure()

x = np.array([0, 4])
y = np.array([0, 0])
z = np.array([[0, 0], [2.2, 2.2]])
xe = np.array([0, 4, 4, 0, 0])
ye = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
ze = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])


fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        surfacecolor=[0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
        opacity=0.15,
        ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
    x=xe, y=ye, z=ze,
    mode="lines",
    line=dict(
        color='#ff0000',
        width=2
    )
))

x = np.array([4, 4])
y = np.array([0, 2.5])
z = np.array([[0, 2.2], [0, 2.2]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        surfacecolor=[0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
        opacity=0.15,
        ))


x = np.array([4, 0])
y = np.array([2.5, 2.5])
z = np.array([[0, 0], [2.2, 2.2]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        surfacecolor=[0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
        opacity=0.15,
        ))

x = np.array([0, 0])
y = np.array([2.5, 0])
z = np.array([[0, 2.2], [0, 2.2]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Surface(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        surfacecolor=[0.2, 0.5, 0.8],
        opacity=0.15,
        ))
```

The result looks nice, I can see the walls and the edges of one of them, but with this method I am not able to draw walls that are not parallel to X and Y axis.

[Plotly rectangle room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkZG2.png)

Is there a better way to draw these 3D rectangles easily in the space? Can you point me in the right direction? Sorry for the low skills (I amd just starting to learn) and for the pseudocodes (I had to remove many useless things from a bigger code I wrote).

EDIT:
I found a possible solution but it is not very comfortable, in my opinion. If you know a better way to do this, I would really appreciate it. My solution would look like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog
fig = go.Figure()

x = np.array([0, 4, 4, 0, 0])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
z = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])
xe = np.array([0, 4, 4, 0, 0])
ye = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
ze = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        color='#2244ff',
        opacity=0.15,
        delaunayaxis='y'
        ))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
    x=xe, y=ye, z=ze,
    mode="lines",
    line=dict(
        color='#ff0000',
        width=2
    )
))

x = np.array([4, 6, 6, 4, 4])
y = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 0])
z = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        color='#2244ff',
        opacity=0.15,
        delaunayaxis='x'
        ))

x = np.array([6, 4, 4, 6, 6])
y = np.array([2, 4, 4, 2, 2])
z = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        color='#2244ff',
        opacity=0.15,
        delaunayaxis='x'
        ))

x = np.array([4, 0, 0, 4, 4])
y = np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])
z = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        color='#2244ff',
        opacity=0.15,
        delaunayaxis='y'
        ))

x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
y = np.array([4, 0, 0, 4, 4])
z = np.array([0, 0, 2.2, 2.2, 0])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Mesh3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        color='#2244ff',
        opacity=0.15,
        delaunayaxis='x'
        ))
```

This allows me to draw walls which are not parallel to axis X or Y, but I have to know the directions of the walls to set a proper delaunayaxis, which is not so easy if an external user introduces the coordinates of vertex of the desired room. So any suggestion will be very welcome. I attach here the plot I generated with this new approach.

[Room with 5 sides using Mesh3d in plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0MqX.png)

EDIT2:
I am about to finally solve my own question. I can draw the walls with a surface. Here is my pseudocode:

```
x1[0,0]=xmin
x1[0,1]=xmax
x1[1,0]=xmin
x1[1,1]=xmax
y1[0,0]=ymin
y1[0,1]=ymax
y1[1,0]=ymin
y1[1,1]=ymax
z1[0,0]=zmin
z1[0,1]=zmin
z1[1,0]=zmax
z1[1,1]=zmax
wall11 = go.Surface(x=x1, y=y1, z=z1,
                 colorscale = colorscale,
                 showscale=False,
                 opacity=0.5)
fig =  go.Figure(data=[wall1])
```

Then I can loop through an array of walls' coordinates.
If you think the question is not useful, you can delete it. Anyway, if you find an even better way to do this, I would like to take a look at it.
Thank you.